# how to Calculate Equilibrium point of equations

Tags: digital-logic, boost

I was reading an article about finite state machine and boost converter.
I don't know how to calculate the equilibrium point
$$v^* $$

for convenience the equation of v is
$$ v = \frac{v_in}{1-d_n} $$
Can anybody paste link about how the calculation made here.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Where did you get this snip that says trivial calculations?

Comment: At the very least we need equations (21) through (24) -- as it stands your question is like showing us a picture of a wheel and saying "what color is the car?"

Comment: I add link of document. [article-link](https://gukly.com/media/profiles/proofs/fsm-model-converter.pdf). It's Page no 6.

Comment: How is a programming method (the finite state machine) related to boost converters ?

Comment: @GrahamStevenson Boost converter work on the pwm signal given. if we change the duty cycle of the pwm signal with programming we can control the output of boost converter with FSM

Comment: You're suggesting that the PWM duty cycle be controlled by a micro running a finite state machine ?  Interesting. I'm unsure how you would achieve that,

Comment: This is already done. I am student just reading it to understand that and continue from where they left. but stuck in mathematics